# File upload not working after changing models format

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-models

I have a model class similar to following -

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%M/%D')
```

Everything is working fine and files are uploaded successfully based on directory structure.

Now I don't want to upload files in this format but simply all files in one folder so I changed the logic ..

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

Now It is not uploading the files and throwing error. Maybe I need to run some command but I do not know what ??

Please suggest something

**Edit1:**

Ok .. I found that the actual problem lies somewhere else.

I have a view like this - (please ignore the bad spacing but that is fine in actual code)

```
def lists(request):

   // Problematic Code Start
   path = settings.MEDIA_URL + 'upload/location.txt' 
   f = open(path, 'w')
   myfile = File(f)
   myfile.write('Hello World')
   myfile.closed
   f.closed
   // Problematic Code ends


   # Handle file upload

   if request.method == 'POST':

       form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

       if form.is_valid():
           filename = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
           filename.save()
           # Redirect to the document list after POST
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sdm:lists'))
       #return render_to_response(reverse('sdm:lists'))
   else:
       form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

       # Load documents for the list page
       documents = Document.objects.all()

       # Render list page with the documents and the form
       return render_to_response(
           'sdm/lists.html',
           {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
           context_instance=RequestContext(request)
       )
```

When I remove the problematic code , everything works fine. (ignore the purpose of this weird code, actual interest is something bigger)

`MEDIA_URL=/media/`

Here is the error:

```
 IOError at /sdm/lists

 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/upload/location.txt'
```

Although File Exists and all permissions are `www-data:www-data` with `755`

Comment: Please give us the error.

Comment: @scriptmonster please have a look at the update

Comment: Are you running your project with `./manage.py runserver` or with modwsgi.

Comment: I am running this server on live deployment with apache

Comment: There is a problem on accessing the file. Your code is ok. You need to look file and permissions twice.

Comment: "problematic" code indeed - whoever wrote this should find another job. This code is wrong in more than one way (using MEDIA_URL instead of MEDIA_ROOT and misusing Python's dead simple file objects) _and_ totally useless. Just remove it and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"problematic" code indeed - whoever wrote this should find another job. This code is wrong in more than one way (using MEDIA_URL instead of MEDIA_ROOT - which is the cause of the IOError you get - and also badly misusing Python's dead simple file objects) *and* totally useless, and looks like a leftover of someone programming by accident. To make a long story short : just remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: Actually you are right .. By giving absolute path it worked out. About the code, as I already said in explanation that don't go behind the weird logic, the purpose was just to find out how to access a system file with django which you pointed out. Thanks

Comment: Accessing the filesystem has nothing to do with Django, it's just plain Python (and it's well documented). wrt/ the Django part, the `MEDIA_URL` setting and the related `MEDIA_ROOT` one are also fully documented. If you're the author of the "problematic" code then do yourself a favour and learn to properly use Python's standard features (like opening, reading, writing and closing a file) instead of trying just anything that comes to your mind hoping it will magically work (ProgrammingByAccident anyone ?).